# How to get children and grandchildren in sitecore

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore8

I am trying to make a left navigation and I'm able to get the children of a parent item, but not the grandchildren. Theres the Main folder with 4 folders under it that each have 3 items, all using the same template.

```
> Main /   
      Folder 1/
>      item1
>      item2
>      item3   
      Folder 2/
>      item1
>      item2
>      item3   
      Folder 3/
>      item1
>      item2
>      item3   
      Folder 4/
>      item1
>      item2
>      item3
```

I use a repeater to start:

```
<ul>
    <asp:Literal ID="litFolder" runat="server" />
    <asp:Repeater ID="leftNav" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="leftNav_ItemDataBound">
        <HeaderTemplate>
        <li>
        </HeaderTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptsubleftNav" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptsubleftNav_ItemDataBound">

                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <ul>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                        <li>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HLMainnav" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
                        </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </ul>
                </FooterTemplate>

            </asp:Repeater>
        </ItemTemplate>

        <FooterTemplate>
        </li>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

The front end is setup to make them links but currently its only pulling in the folders, which in essence is making them links instead of the items in the folder.

```cs
 public partial class LeftNav : System.Web.UI.UserControl
 {

     Item currentItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;


     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         leftNav.DataSource = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/Main/").Children;
         leftNav.DataBind();

     }

     public void leftNav_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
     {
         Item currentItem = (Item)e.Item.DataItem;
     ((Literal)e.Item.FindControl("litFolder")).Text = currentItem.Name;

        if (currentItem != null)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                var subNav = e.Item.FindControl("rptsubleftNav") as Repeater;

                if (subNav != null)
                {
                    subNav.DataSource = currentItem.GetChildren();
                    subNav.DataBind();
                    currentItem.ToString();

                    HyperLink HLMainnav = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("HLMainnav");
                    HLMainnav.NavigateUrl = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(currentItem);
                    HLMainnav.Text = currentItem.Name;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void rptsubleftNav_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

How do I get the next level and set them as the links instead of the folders?

(UPDATED)
I have the folders and their children, but the names aren't displayed. I also tried using <%# Eval("title") %> on the front end, but it is saying that the Sitecore Item doesn't have that field when it does. So not sure how its showing the items correctly but without the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add another repeater inside `leftNav` repeater `ItemTemplate` tag.

Then in `leftNav_ItemDataBound` method, get children of `currentItem` and assign them as a datasource for the new repeater.

Here is similar question [(Sitecore) Navigation with Subnavigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370436/sitecore-navigation-with-subnavigation)

That's it.

Comment: Don't forget to exclude the folder items from generating links. You can use something like item.TemplateID == [FolderTemplateID] to exclude them from the list or to not generate links for them.

Comment: this works but for whatever reason, it is not displaying the name of the folder or the item, I set currentItem to string, but its still not showing up

Comment: You would need edit your question and post updated code below the existing

Comment: Why do you have **else** part in `if (subNav != null) ... else `? It means that it will only execute this code if there is no subNav, and subNav is always there, right? (btw I don't see subNav in your ascx code at all - I think you forgot to update this one)

Comment: when I add it in the if statement, it says that HLMainnav.NavigateUrl = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(currentItem); is not set to an instance of an object, when it clearly was before

Comment: Add `<asp:Literal ID="litFolder" runat="server" />` and use `((Literal)e.Item.FindControl("litFolder")).Text = currentItem.Name;`

Comment: added the literal, now that is throwing the instance object error, I moved the literal around up front inside different repeaters and to no avail

Comment: If you're still getting object ref errors, move the FindControl call for litFolder in to the if statement check for ListItemType.Item - it's probably trying to find the litFolder control in your HeaderTemplate or FooterTemplate.